# Can't Remotely Debug Tomcat Running on CentOS Virtual Machine from Eclipse on Host Windows 7

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging

## Setup

### VMWare Virtual Machine

- CentOS 5.5 64-bit
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
- Tomcat 6.0

### Host Machine

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Oracle/Sun JDK 1.6 64-bit
- Eclipse Helios for Java EE developers

## Problem

My eclipse Remote Java Application has following connection properties:

```
Host: 192.168.94.133
Port: 8000
```

When I run the above configuration, I get:

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
```

Nothing new comes out of tomcat's log.

But when I telnet from the windows box:

```
bash-3.2$ telnet 192.168.94.133 8000
Trying 192.168.94.133...
Connected to 192.168.94.133.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Every time I try the above telnet, tomcat spits this out in the log:

```
Debugger failed to attach: timeout during handshake
```

Because of the telnet behavior, I think the issue is in Eclipse... I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks,
-Dave

Comment: Double-check that Eclipse is actually trying to use port 8000.  If you can telnet to 8000 but Eclipse gets "Connection refused", then my money is on Eclipse trying to use a different port.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably trying to connect **twice** to port 8000 from Eclipse (without noticing).

Switch to the Debug Perspective explicitly ("Window - Open Perspective - Debug") and see if you are connected.

Answer (score 0):

Settings required in Tomcat 1)Create setenv.sh file under */tomcat/bin/. The location will be same as the catalina.sh file

2)Place the below content inside it. export CATALINA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

Now start the Tomcat server. Once it is started please proceed with the below steps.

Settings required in Eclipse

3)In Eclipse go to Windows-->Preference--> General-->Network Connection --> Active Provider should be Direct. After changing to direct restart the eclipse.

4)In eclipse right click on project and debug as ->debug configuration ->Remote java application ->Create new configuration. Fill the below fields Name: as your wish Project:Select the project which you need to debug. ConnectionType: Standard socket attach Host: Localhost Port: 8000(It should be same as mentioned in point 2) Then click debug.

The debug will start at port 8000. Now you can verify by keeping breakpoints.